# Sums of Continuous Random Variables using Convolutions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, convolution

Suppose that $R^2 = X^2 + Y^2$. Find $f_{R^2}$ and $f_R$ if
$f_X(x) = f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
1/2 &\text{if}\, -1 \leq x \leq 1\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Since we are not given the distribution I know we have to use convolutions. Namely,

$$f_{R^2}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X^2}(t)f_{Y^2}(x-t)dt$$

My problem is that I was given $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ and not $f_{X^2}(x)$ and $f_{Y^2}(y)$.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the distribution of $X^2$ from the distribution for $X.$ For $l\in[0,1],$ the CDF of $X^2$ is

$$F_{X^2}(l) =P(X^2<l) = P(-\sqrt{l}<X<\sqrt{l}) =\sqrt l.$$
The PDF is the derivative of the CDF, so $$ f_{X^2}(l) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{l}}$$ for $l\in [0,1]$ (and zero outside that support).

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get $f_{R^2} = \frac{\pi}{4} \text{for} 0 \leq x \leq 1$ which matches with the right answer. However i'm stuck in trying to get $f_R$ from $f_{R^2}$

Comment: You need the piece of the distribution from $1<x<2$ too. Getting $f_R$ from $f_{R^2}$ is an exercise very similar to what I did above to get $f_{X^2}$ from $f_X.$

Comment: You're right! I found $f_R$ for $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$ which is $x\pi/2$ but I'm having trouble with the distribution of $1<x<2$. Sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: It's okay. The following indefinite integral will probably help: $$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx = \arcsin(\sqrt{x}) + C.$$